# How to Authenticate WP REST API with JWT Authentication using Fetch API

Tags: rest-api, authentication

My goal is to send *user comments* with a POST request from a server-side Lambda function to my WordPress API. I'm using [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/) and [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/).

When someone leaves a comment in the comment form of my Gatsby front-end, Netlify receives a [form submission event](https://www.netlify.com/docs/functions/#event-triggered-functions) and a [Netlify Lambda function](https://www.netlify.com/docs/functions/#javascript-lambda-functions) gets called. It is in this function that I will prepare and send the comment to my WordPress site through the [WP-REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/).

The problem is that my function seems to fail silently. This may be partly due to how Netlify makes available its Functions logs. My hunch was that *some form of Authentication* was needed to POST a comment to WP REST API so I went ahead and installed the [JWT Authentication Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/) (mainly because I believe it is more secure that Basic Auth, though I'm not sure).

I went through the docs for the JWT plugin and made the necessary changes to my `.htaccess` and my `wp-config.php` file including enabling CORS support and defining a new secret key:

`define('JWT_AUTH_SECRET_KEY', 'your-top-secret-key');`

In my Lambda function I make a post request the end JWT endpoint:

```
fetch('https://example.com/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token', {
     // credentials: 'include',
     headers: new Headers({
        'Authenticate': 'Basic {what do I put here?}' // Do I need "Basic"?
     })
  })
  .then(response => {
     console.log("Did we get a response? ", response)
     return response.json()
  })
  .then(myJson => {
     console.log(JSON.stringify(myJson))
  })
  .catch(error => {
     console.log("error: ", error);
     throw new Error('Something bad happened.', error)
  })
```

My confusion comes in *how* to properly set up an Authentication call, *if* I need to authenticate at all, and whether or not I should be sending my WordPress`username:password` or the *JSON Web Token* that I defined in my `wp-config.php`.

And what should the format of the username/password be? Should it URL-encoded, i.e: `username=admin&password=Str0ngPass` or just `username:password'.

[This question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/299542/how-to-make-jwt-authenticated-requests-to-the-wordpress-api) seems to offer a working approach but I am not using Postman and can't even get a token from my Fetch call. A couple more answers that I found are more theoretical and don't offer much in terms of code examples:

- [Using JWT to authenticate a user with an external system?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/203686/using-jwt-to-authenticate-a-user-with-an-external-system)
- [Set up Wp Authentication from external API](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/268665/set-up-wp-authentication-from-external-api)

I also discovered [JWT Web Tokens for Node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken). Maybe I should implement it that way?

I've found the documentation surrounding using fetch to authenticate to be a little patchy. Any help would be greatly appreciated and I'm happy to supply any more code/info that you need.

Answer (score 6):

> ```
> 'Authenticate': 'Basic {what do I put here?}' // Do I need "Basic"?
> ```

No, it's not `Basic`. It's **`Bearer`**. And the header is **`Authorization`**.

So first, obtain a token from `/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token`:

```js
fetch( 'http://example.com/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify( {
        // Username of a user on the WordPress website in which the REST API request
        // is being made to.
        username: 'user',
        // And the above user's password.
        password: 'pass'
    } ),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
} )
.then( res => res.json() )
.then( res => console.log( res.token ) );
```

At this point: `.then( res => console.log( res.token ) )`, you can cache the token, for example in the browser cookies (`document.cookie`). I mean, if there were no errors (returned by the REST API endpoint), then the token is stored in `res.token`.

After you obtained a valid token, you can then use the token when making a request to a REST API endpoint such as ["*Create a Comment*"](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/comments/#create-a-comment) — set the `Authorization` header and set its value to: `Bearer <token>`, where in the above example, `<token>` is the value of the `res.token`.

```js
fetch( 'http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/comments', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify( {
        author_email: 'test@example.com',
        author_name: 'Test via REST API',
        content: 'Test comment',
        post: 123
    } ),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: 'Bearer <token>'
    }
} )
.then( res => res.json() )
.then( res => console.log( res ) );
```

### Make sure the `Authorization` header is enabled

Because that header is ***required by the [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/)***.

And in my case, the `Authorization` header (which in PHP can be accessed via `$_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']`) was missing/disabled, so I had to add this to the Apache's configuration file (`httpd.conf`): (*requires restarting the Apache server*)

```
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
```

I did try to add this to the (root) `.htaccess` file, but it didn't work for me:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

I hope that helps you and/or someone else having problems with the `Authorization` header. :)

### Resources

- https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie
- https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/comments/