# Not able to delete media by REST API

Tags: rest-api

I'm following the [official documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/media/#delete-a-media-item) to requesting the REST API endpoint to delete media.

I already have [Basic Auth](https://github.com/WP-API/Basic-Auth) plugin installed in my WP and I'm able to upload media by REST API, but when I try to delete it, I'm getting error 401, "You don't have permission to delete this post".

What should I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Why not use the standard cookie [authentication](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/)? And what's your code?

Comment: I have a bunch of images to import and remove (more than 1000), so I created a PHP script to do this. So I'm not in Wordpress website context

Comment: Have you tried using the JWT [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/)? And is the HTTP `Authorization` header enabled on your site?

Comment: I'll try the JWT plugin so, I'm not sure about Authorization header, but I'm able to upload by REST api, so I think the header is fine.

Comment: Ok, I suggest you to try the JWT plugin first. You can also check this [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/333772/137402) and if you got stuck, you can update this question.